# Only specific user group should have permission to create and close work item

Tags: tfs

Is there is a possibility in TFS 2013 where a particular work item like Bug an d Change Request has to be created and closed by Testing team and task by developers.

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot achieve that as the requirements conflict each other.

- You can set the permission `Edit work items in this node` for a
  specific user group on an specific Area. **But it applies to all the
  work item types**.
- You can customize work tracking experience for restricting access to
  work items:

  For example, you can prevent the majority of project contributors
  from creating the work items by [adding WITs to the Hidden Categories
  group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/use-categories-to-group-work-item-types?view=vsts). You can [create a hyperlink to a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=vsts&tabs=browser) that opens
  the work item form and share that link with those team members who
  you do want to create them. **But you cannot prevent other team members
  closing the work items.**

> **[You can restrict access to work tracking objects in one of two ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#additional-options-for-restricting-access-to-work-items):**
>
> - By [adding WITs to the Hidden Categories group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/use-categories-to-group-work-item-types?view=vsts), you can prevent the majority of project contributors from creating them. You can [create a hyperlink to a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=vsts&tabs=browser) that opens the work item form and share that link with those team members who you do want to create them.
> - [Set a condition field rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts), [a condition-based field rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules?view=vsts) or    a combination of the two that applies to a group. You can restrict changes from being made to a field by specifying a qualifying rule and making it apply for a specific group.
>     Conditional rules can    include **CANNOTLOSEVALUE**, **EMPTY**,
>     **FROZEN**, **NOTSAMEAS**,    **READONLY**, and **REQUIRED** elements.
>
> For more information about how to customize WITs, see [Modify or add a
>   custom work item type (WIT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=vsts).

[image]